# The $K$-moment problem for measures with countable support?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, optimization

Roughly the $K$-moment problem can be described as:

> Given a subset $K$ of $\mathbb{R}$ and a sequence of real numbers $(q)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, does there exists a Borel measure $\mu$ with support $K$ such that $(q)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is it's sequence of moments, that is
>
> $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} x^n\mu(dx)=q_n?$$

Depending on the assumptions on $K$ (for example, $K=\mathbb{R},[0,\infty)$ or $K$ is a semi-algebraic set) different necessary or sufficient (and sometimes both) conditions for the problem to have a solution in terms of so called moment matrices can be derived (see, for example, this [survey](http://homepages.cwi.nl/%7Emonique/files/moment-ima.pdf)). In particular, if $K$ contains finitely many elements, then some rather strong conditions can be derived (see the survey).

My question is, what about the case in which $K$ has countably many elements? Does anyone know a good reference for this? In particular, I'm looking for conditions that are stronger the general ones that can be derived for the case $K=\mathbb{R}$.

EDIT: I'm actually more interested in the case where $K\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and is countable, so any reference that instead deals directly with the generalisation would also be great.